# Tree of objects using c?

Tags: c, windows

I use this code to list processes:

```
       //Creating ListBox
        hPNList=CreateWindow(TEXT("ListBox"),TEXT(""),WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|LBS_SORT|LBS_NOTIFY,30,132,185,380,hWnd,(HMENU)PNLIST_ID,
        GetModuleHandle(NULL),NULL);

        //changing Font
        SendMessage( hPNList ,WM_SETFONT ,(WPARAM) GetStockObject(DEFAULT_GUI_FONT ),TRUE);

        //making list
        ProcessCount =getprocesslist(pro);

        //adding to list  
        for ( i = 0; i < ProcessCount; i++) 
        { 
            int pos = (int)SendMessage(hPNList, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, 
                (LPARAM) pro[i].szExeFile); 
            // Set the array index of the player as item data.
            // This enables us to retrieve the item from the array
            // even after the items are sorted by the list box.
            SendMessage(hPNList, LB_SETITEMDATA, pos, (LPARAM) pro[i].th32ProcessID ); 
        }
```

Now I want to show that in a tree style.Can anybody help me how to do it?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: I want to show windows processes in a tree style.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: The question edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Using Tree-View Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773409%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for a general overview of how to work with the native tree view controls in Windows. In particular, see [How to Add Tree-View Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298347%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for code examples on how to add a hierarchy of items to a tree view.

It boils down to:

1. Use the [`CreateWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632679%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function while specifying [`WC_TREEVIEW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775491%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#WC_TREEVIEW) as the window class
2. Send the [`TVM_INSERTITEM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773733%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message to the tree window to populate it with tree items.